# Clipped projected gradient descent gets stuck in local minima

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I have a Linear Programming problem of the form min $cx$ s.t. $Ax=b$, $x\geq0$ which I want to solve using projected gradient descent.

I derived the projection operators
$P = I - A^T (A * A^T)^{-1} * A$
and
$Q =  A^T * (A*A^T)^{-1}*b$ required to project a point on the feasible set.

Given an initial guess $x_0$ and step size $\alpha$, my algorithm is as follows:

for $i = 0...$

$x_{i+1} = P(x_i - \alpha * c) + Q$
$x_{i+1} = max(x_i, 0)$

In most cases, the algorithm converges to the optimal value. Some other times it gets stuck in some local minima.

What is the justification for this?
Thanks in advance!